# Отваливается DNS (Linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, vpn

VPN без указания 1.1.1.1 DNS серверов для IPv4:

```
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=88 ttl=58 time=179 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=89 ttl=58 time=46.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=90 ttl=58 time=52.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=91 ttl=58 time=169 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=92 ttl=58 time=1030 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=93 ttl=58 time=53.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=94 ttl=58 time=3591 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=95 ttl=58 time=2576 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=96 ttl=58 time=11253 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=97 ttl=58 time=10229 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=98 ttl=58 time=9305 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=99 ttl=58 time=8288 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=100 ttl=58 time=8088 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=101 ttl=58 time=7089 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=102 ttl=58 time=6069 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=103 ttl=58 time=5045 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=104 ttl=58 time=4270 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=105 ttl=58 time=3246 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=106 ttl=58 time=2399 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=107 ttl=58 time=1375 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=108 ttl=58 time=491 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=109 ttl=58 time=508 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=110 ttl=58 time=110 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=111 ttl=58 time=3505 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=112 ttl=58 time=3344 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=113 ttl=58 time=2320 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=114 ttl=58 time=1296 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=115 ttl=58 time=726 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=116 ttl=58 time=3250 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=117 ttl=58 time=2244 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=118 ttl=58 time=1645 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=119 ttl=58 time=902 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=120 ttl=58 time=1032 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=121 ttl=58 time=8113 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=122 ttl=58 time=7158 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=123 ttl=58 time=6144 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=124 ttl=58 time=5120 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=125 ttl=58 time=4140 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=126 ttl=58 time=3120 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=127 ttl=58 time=2096 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=128 ttl=58 time=1068 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=129 ttl=58 time=67.10 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=130 ttl=58 time=1279 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=131 ttl=58 time=1434 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=132 ttl=58 time=551 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=133 ttl=58 time=47.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=134 ttl=58 time=47.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=135 ttl=58 time=332 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=136 ttl=58 time=46.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=137 ttl=58 time=58.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=138 ttl=58 time=48.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=139 ttl=58 time=59.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=140 ttl=58 time=63.10 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=141 ttl=58 time=675 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=142 ttl=58 time=106 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=143 ttl=58 time=1379 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=144 ttl=58 time=1402 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=145 ttl=58 time=401 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=146 ttl=58 time=1176 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=147 ttl=58 time=1096 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=148 ttl=58 time=1539 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=149 ttl=58 time=1645 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=150 ttl=58 time=683 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=151 ttl=58 time=113 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=152 ttl=58 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=153 ttl=58 time=53.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=154 ttl=58 time=52.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=155 ttl=58 time=49.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=156 ttl=58 time=403 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=157 ttl=58 time=64.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=158 ttl=58 time=56.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=159 ttl=58 time=50.10 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=160 ttl=58 time=50.10 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=161 ttl=58 time=47.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=162 ttl=58 time=50.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=163 ttl=58 time=53.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=164 ttl=58 time=46.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=165 ttl=58 time=246 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=166 ttl=58 time=48.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=167 ttl=58 time=51.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=168 ttl=58 time=46.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=169 ttl=58 time=49.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=170 ttl=58 time=52.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=171 ttl=58 time=47.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=172 ttl=58 time=374 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=173 ttl=58 time=53.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=174 ttl=58 time=46.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=175 ttl=58 time=47.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=176 ttl=58 time=53.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=177 ttl=58 time=51.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=178 ttl=58 time=49.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=179 ttl=58 time=46.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=180 ttl=58 time=46.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=181 ttl=58 time=52.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=182 ttl=58 time=50.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=183 ttl=58 time=46.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=184 ttl=58 time=58.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=185 ttl=58 time=46.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=186 ttl=58 time=50.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=187 ttl=58 time=47.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=188 ttl=58 time=53.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=189 ttl=58 time=115 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=190 ttl=58 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=191 ttl=58 time=46.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=192 ttl=58 time=46.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=193 ttl=58 time=49.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=194 ttl=58 time=47.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=195 ttl=58 time=48.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=196 ttl=58 time=50.0 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=197 ttl=58 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=198 ttl=58 time=49.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=199 ttl=58 time=298 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=200 ttl=58 time=46.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=201 ttl=58 time=47.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=202 ttl=58 time=46.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=203 ttl=58 time=47.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=204 ttl=58 time=51.2 ms
```

VPN с указанием 1.1.1.1:

```
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=141 ttl=58 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=142 ttl=58 time=57.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=143 ttl=58 time=337 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=144 ttl=58 time=48.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=145 ttl=58 time=51.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=146 ttl=58 time=51.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=147 ttl=58 time=333 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=148 ttl=58 time=465 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=149 ttl=58 time=48.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=150 ttl=58 time=59.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=151 ttl=58 time=91.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=152 ttl=58 time=52.10 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=153 ttl=58 time=313 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=154 ttl=58 time=50.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=155 ttl=58 time=324 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=156 ttl=58 time=50.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=157 ttl=58 time=8142 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=158 ttl=58 time=7159 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=159 ttl=58 time=6131 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=160 ttl=58 time=5111 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=161 ttl=58 time=4087 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=162 ttl=58 time=3063 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=163 ttl=58 time=2039 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=164 ttl=58 time=1015 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=165 ttl=58 time=149 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=166 ttl=58 time=152 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=167 ttl=58 time=288 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=168 ttl=58 time=64.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=169 ttl=58 time=57.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=170 ttl=58 time=49.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=171 ttl=58 time=247 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=172 ttl=58 time=51.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=173 ttl=58 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=174 ttl=58 time=116 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=175 ttl=58 time=328 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=176 ttl=58 time=112 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=177 ttl=58 time=48.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=178 ttl=58 time=51.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=179 ttl=58 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=180 ttl=58 time=48.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=181 ttl=58 time=49.10 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=182 ttl=58 time=49.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=183 ttl=58 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=184 ttl=58 time=52.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=185 ttl=58 time=55.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=186 ttl=58 time=58.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=187 ttl=58 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=188 ttl=58 time=49.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=189 ttl=58 time=57.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=190 ttl=58 time=48.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=191 ttl=58 time=48.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=192 ttl=58 time=246 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=193 ttl=58 time=52.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=194 ttl=58 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=195 ttl=58 time=51.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=196 ttl=58 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=197 ttl=58 time=51.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=198 ttl=58 time=47.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=199 ttl=58 time=57.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=200 ttl=58 time=48.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=201 ttl=58 time=49.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=202 ttl=58 time=50.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=203 ttl=58 time=47.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=204 ttl=58 time=51.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=205 ttl=58 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=206 ttl=58 time=48.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=207 ttl=58 time=50.10 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=208 ttl=58 time=48.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=209 ttl=58 time=111 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=210 ttl=58 time=49.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=211 ttl=58 time=51.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=212 ttl=58 time=8826 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=213 ttl=58 time=7887 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=214 ttl=58 time=6863 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=215 ttl=58 time=5839 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=216 ttl=58 time=4815 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=217 ttl=58 time=3791 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=218 ttl=58 time=2856 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=219 ttl=58 time=1832 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=220 ttl=58 time=858 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=221 ttl=58 time=107 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=222 ttl=58 time=49.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=223 ttl=58 time=52.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=224 ttl=58 time=411 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=225 ttl=58 time=56.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=226 ttl=58 time=176 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=227 ttl=58 time=65.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=228 ttl=58 time=117 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=229 ttl=58 time=50.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=230 ttl=58 time=52.8 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=231 ttl=58 time=329 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=232 ttl=58 time=50.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=233 ttl=58 time=55.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=234 ttl=58 time=60.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=235 ttl=58 time=49.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=236 ttl=58 time=52.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=237 ttl=58 time=51.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=238 ttl=58 time=48.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=239 ttl=58 time=50.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=240 ttl=58 time=51.6 ms
```

Без VPN тоже есть скачки, но не большие:

```
554 packets transmitted, 510 received, +1 duplicates, 7.94224% packet loss, time 887ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 23.676/28.341/200.589/9.449 ms
```

У провайдера нет тех. работ, а с VPN проблем у других пользователей нет. Чую, что-то у меня на Ubuntu не так. В маршрутизаторе стоят как стандартные DNS: 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1. IPv6 отключен везде.

Comment: и? в чем проблема?

Comment: попингуйте роутер (свой). В идеале, пинг будет минимальным. Если он также гулят, то проблема в линке между ним и Вами. Если у Вас WiFi, то подобные колебания могут быть нормой

Comment: кстати, DNS с временем пинга по ip-адресу абсолютно ни как не связан...

Comment: @michael_best, валиться интернет постоянно, периодически проскакивает: "Невозможно найти адрес удаленного хоста" и потом опять работает. Проскакивает тогда когда time=7159 ms и т.д

Comment: откуда вы вообще это достали?

Comment: @michael_best, личное наблюдение. Глючит DNS ужстно при использовании VPN...

Comment: так может dns бегает через vpn, и пинги через него ходят (что логично). А сам vpn находится где то в Австралии. Тогда картина логична